# Qt: convert a mouse press QPoint to a relative point inside a QRect

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I have two `QRect`s lined side by side:

```py
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    self.rect1 = QRect(0, 0, 500, 40)
    painter.fillRect(self.rect1, Qt.GlobalColor.black)
    self.rect2 = QRect(500, 0, 500, 40)
    painter.fillRect(self.rect2, Qt.GlobalColor.white)
```

If user clicks somewhere in second `QRect`, I want to know the location of the click relative to the `(0, 0)` of the `QRect`:

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    pos = event.pos()

    if self.rect2.contains(pos):
        relative_pos = QPoint(pos.x() - self.rect2.x(), pos.y() - self.rect2.y())
```

Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: `pos - rect2.topLeft()`?

Comment: @G.M. oh, didn't know that was possible. Much cleaner than what I have. Thank you.

Comment: You may try using transformations https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#translate @Neat

Comment: @Neat Note that you shouldn't normally define instance attributes in `paintEvent` *unless* you need very specific behavior based on the painting context (which is a very rare case), especially considering that paint events may occur very frequently and at unexpected moments (Qt "decides" when it needs it).

Comment: @musicamante oh, no, the post is just a sort of pseudocode, I don't actually have instance attributes defined in the method.